# How can I provide a mechanism for users to increase the gameplay speed?

Tags: cocos2d, cocos2d-x

I am developing a tower-defense game and I want to permit user to change game engine speed ,for example rotation speed of towers,rockets speed ,enemies moving speed ,counters and etc proportionally. 
Is it any way to increase/decrease speed of game engine or any other way similar to it?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You don't speed up the engine, you speed up your units and their actions. For example, when you update an enemy, you usually do something like `enemyDirection * enemySpeed * timePassed` to get their new position. Now, if you want to double or halve the speed of gameplay, you just add this in as a factor: `enemyDirection * enemySpeed * timePassed * gameplaySpeedFactor`. That's roughly the principle behind it.